# Is it a structural concern that my plumber cut through 6 studs to install water line?

Tags: plumbing, walls, structural, exterior, studs

We had a plumber come out and install a water line for a pot filler and it looks like he cut through 6 studs without our permission on the exterior wall of the house. We are worried it could cause structural issues. Can anyone provide an opinion?

[image]

Comment: Are they 2x6 or 2x4 studs and how deep are the cutouts?  Usually people drill holes for pipes in studs/joists.  If in a cold climate, should try to not place water pipes in exterior walls.

Comment: How deep is the notch and what size stud?

Comment: What does the larger structure look like? At first glance I would say yes, a beam's strength is only as much as its smallest cross section, and it looks like that's been decimated (not to mention buckling length is reduced).  How much of the beams is left at the cuts?

Comment: Beams are horizontal, @MiG, posts are vertical. ;)

Comment: Not my native language, where the word is the same for both categories :)

Comment: Is this a 1 story home? What is the size of the house? Is this in an end wall or side wall? Are you located in a seismic area or high wind area?

Comment: Is this a bearing wall (are trusses sitting on the wall)?

Answer (score 1):

Those studs can be notched up to 25% if it's a load bearing wall (likely) or exterior wall (very lilely due to insulation). So for a 2x4 that could be notched 7/8in deep, for a 2x6 it could be just over 1.25in.

Those lines look like they are under 1.5in since they appear to have a smaller diameter than the 1.5in lumber. So this could be marginally ok.

For a better answer you'd have to let us know what the depth of those studs is (e.g. 3.5in for a 2x4, and 5.25in for a 2x6), and what the size of the notch is. It could help to know whether the wall is load bearing, but that may be more difficult to determine by a lay person.

[image]

Ref: Western Wood Products Association http://files.engineering.com/download.aspx?folder=2fda658c-dda7-403f-9165-d97f6092084c&file=notch_and_holes.pdf